# How can row 1 (first row of sheet) be excluded in getActiveRange() when it is in active range (Google Sheets)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, row, google-sheets-macros

How is it possible to exclude the top row or cell of sheet from getActiveRange() if it exists? How can shift() be integrated? A selection is only made within a column to define the area to be used in column 3.

```
function x() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = s.getActiveRange().getLastColumn();
  var activeRange = s.getActiveRange().offset(0, -lastColumn+3); // column 3
  if (activeRange.getRow() == 1) {
    s.getRange('F1').copyTo(activeRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  }
  else {
  s.getRange('F1').copyTo(activeRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  }
}
```

If cells (adjacent) are activated within a column and only row 1 (title row), 5, 8 and 9 are displayed because of a filter, for example. Then F1 (x) is to be inserted into rows 5, 8 and 9 using copyTo(). It is not yet clear to me how I can integrate the suggested solutions. Here are some examples:

1:

```
function getRangeMinusHeaders(range) {
  var height = range.getHeight();
  if (height == 1) {
    return null;
  }
  var width = range.getWidth();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, height-1, width);
}

function x() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = s.getActiveRange().getLastColumn();
  var range = s.getActiveRange().offset(0, -lastColumn+3); // column 3
  s.getRange('F1').copyTo(getRangeMinusHeaders(range), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
}
```

2:

```
function x() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = s.getActiveRange().getLastColumn();
  const activeRange = s.getActiveRange().offset(0, -lastColumn+3); // column 3
  if (activeRange.getRow() == 1) {
    activeRange.getValues();
    activeRange.shift();
    activeRange.forEach(function(row, index) {
      s.getRange('F1').copyTo(row, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    })
  }
  else {
  s.getRange('F1').copyTo(activeRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the Range object corresponding to a given Range, minus a single header row:

```
function getRangeMinusHeaders(range) {
  var height = range.getHeight();
  if (height == 1) {
    return null;
  }
  var width = range.getWidth();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, height-1, width);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use shift when you getValues(), that removes the first row and leaves all others rows.

```
const activeRange = s.getActiveRange().getValues();
activeRange.shift(); // this removes the first row
activeRange.forEach( function(row, index){
  // do something here with each row
  console.log(row)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

```
function x() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = s.getActiveRange()
  if(activeRange.getRow() == 1){
    // If first row is 1, then resize the range.
    var height = activeRange.getHeight();
    activeRange = activeRange.offset(1, 0, height-1);
  }

  Logger.log(activeRange.getA1Notation())
}
```

Comment: I don't want to move the range down by one, because I use filters as well and want to insert an x there. Otherwise it would be row 2. I want to exclude row 1 completely.